# How can I avoid Authenticode signing third-party libraries in a .NET project in an automated build?

Tags: .net, msbuild, code-signing, authenticode

We recently purchased a code-signing certificate and I've been incorporating the code signing step into our automated builds.

Our build script has to build both VB6 and .NET projects, so we currently have a batch file that builds everything. For the .NET projects, our build script calls MSBUILD, passing in a solution file to build. The projects in these solutions have some third-party dependencies, and these files all have the **Copy Local** option turned on in *References*, since they are needed to run the application. In addition, some projects use COM Interop, and so they have automatically-generated Interop assemblies (such as **Interop.MSXML2.dll**) that are also copied to the to the output folder during a build.

I'm trying to figure out an easy to only code sign the files that are compiled during the build (i.e. *our* assemblies), and ignore third-party libraries and Interop assemblies, without resorting to having to call **signtool.exe** on each assembly separately.

Currently, I worked around this by doing the following in the build script:

- Make sure the build cleans all previously-built files
- Compile the .NET solution with MSBUILD, specifying an output folder for the build
- Recursively sign all of the binaries (EXE's, DLL's, OCX's) in the output folder with **signtool.exe**. This signs everything, including the third-party libraries and auto-generated Interop assemblies
- My third-party dependencies are in a separate `lib` folder, so I copy all of the files from `lib` back into the build output folder, overwriting the copies that the build copied there. This way these files are no longer signed, but our assemblies still are

My question is, is there a better way to do this? The only other alternative I can think of is to call **signtool.exe** individually on each assembly that needs signing, but this could be a pain because of the number of projects and the amount of change occurring in them (assemblies get renamed, move, get deleted as the projects evolve). Plus, I don't want to have to guess whether a particular assembly got signed or not, so looping through the files and signing them in bulk makes the most sense to me.

At the same time, however, it doesn't seem right (morally, legally, or otherwise) to arbitrarily sign files that we didn't create with our code-signing certificate.

Or maybe I'm going about this the wrong way altogether?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13123801/321013

Answer (score 1):

If you have license to distribute all of the libraries you're including then I don't think adding your digital signature to them is going to be a problem. I'd just sign everything before creating your installer.

That said, there are some benefits to having everything signed on the user's machine but the most important thing to sign is your installer - that's where most users see the scary messages that a digital signature helps mitigate.

As far as building goes - I use Visual Build Professional to manage all of my build processes and it has an integrated code signing step that I use to sign everything as it is copied. My longest deployment project is over 300 steps in total and does everything from signing to uploading. I'm not associated with Kinook but I try to promote the software - I can't imagine how much time it saves me in a given work week.

Comment: For the legal aspect, I was wondering about licensing as well. I guess I would at least want to avoid re-signing files that were already signed by the original publisher, but maybe it doesn't matter.

Comment: As far as signing all of the files, I agree signing the installers is the most important. The main reason we sign all the other files is so that our software appears as coming from a verified publisher if it requires elevation on Windows Vista and above, since UAC will display "Unknown publisher" otherwise with a big yellow warning icon every time the application needs Administrator rights.

Comment: The legal angle is an interesting question, I've been signing all libraries that I distribute for years without giving it a second thought. I use the signatures to verify integrity more than anything. Is adding your own signature you claiming to be the publisher/original author? I really don't know, and I'm not sure it's a question anyone else has ever thought to ask.

Comment: I'm thinking legal in the sense of abuse of someone else's digital certificates. For example, Stuxnet was a recent virus that used stolen code-signing private keys to digitally-sign the software so that it would spread more quickly. For the companies involved, they have to re-establish their users' trust now. Practically speaking, at least, a digital signature == your company.

Along the same lines, I wouldn't want to necessarily sign something that has some crazy security vulnerability that I don't know about. ;-)

Comment: For proprietary third-party code, code-signing it with your certificate seems like it could be a breach of license agreements, because you are modifying their binaries, which could be interpreted by lawyers as a violation because you are technically tampering with the software. Although, I am not a lawyer so I don't know if that would be a valid argument since the actual machine code isn't modified: it's just additional information added to the PE file. We're a small company though, so I don't want to take chances.