# Should I digitally sign third-party DLLs such as JSON.NET?

Tags: release, digital-signature, code-signing, digital-certificate

I have an application built using a variety of third-party libraries such as JSON.NET.

I would like to ensure that all the DLLs that make up my application are digitally-signed, including the third-party ones. Given that these are not signed by the author, can/should I simply sign the third-party ones myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you talking about strong-naming or about authenticode signatures? The problem with the latter ones is when the authenticode-signed assembly is loaded, .NET validates the certificate and in some configurations (eg. when OCSP needs to be checked and it's not reachable) this can take dozens of seconds. We had to stop signing our assemblies with authenticode and X.509 certificates due to this.

Another drawback is that if the signed assembly is used by malware in some way, some not competent wanna-be-specialists in antivirus companies can (a) mark the assembly as a malware and (b) what is worse, complain to Certificate Authority which issued your code signing certificate, and the certificate will be revoked.

.NET strong-naming (with a keypair without certificate) is more or less your private business.

Update: Authenticode is usually applied to PE format files (EXE and DLL), SYS and CAB. strong-naming is pure .NET technique.

The warning message talks about Authenticode signature. Signing the installer is necessary (that's for sure) and is enough to get rid of the message unless system policies are set to allow only running of signed applications (in which case your application's EXE must be signed as well).

Comment: @EugeneMayevskiEldoS: Thanks. Um, I'm not sure - the difference is not something I'd been aware of. All I'm trying to do is have my application install/run without causing any "this application is not signed" warnings.

Comment: Maybe I should just sign the installer, rather than the DLLs themselves?

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question. The question is *should* one sign third party libraries and applications, it does not ask for the pros and cons for authenticode signing. I came across this answer from Google and I'm quite disappointed that this is the answer I found.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp fyi if you have deployments where you hit certificate revocation list check timeouts, you can fix the issue locally by setting a very low timeout (default is 20 sec) http://rusanu.com/2009/07/24/fix-slow-application-startup-due-to-code-sign-validation/

Comment: Can you disable validating the certs entirely and do it yourself? We already self check for any to tamper. Do id be happy to disable it on third party dlls

Answer (score 21):

I just tried to (unsuccessfully) find an answer to the same question on the internet.

What I have done as a result is to check how Google or Adobe deliver their products and found that every binary in their folders is signed, including third-party ones.

Some examples:

1. Google Chrome includes pepflashplayer.dll, which is copyrighted by Adobe, but digitally signed by "Google Inc."
2. Adobe Reader includes icudt40.dll, which is copyrighted by IBM, but digitally signed by "Adobe Systems"

Thus, I would assume the best practice is to sign all the binaries that make up your application, including third-party ones. It makes sense as it helps you to avoid or at least easily detect tampering if it happens on your customer's machine.